# USB memory stick is no longer recognized as a drive

Tags: usb, mount

I have a USB memory stick that used to work perfectly fine, but then I made a mistake while trying to install a disk image onto it and now no computer recognizes that it is a memory drive. It doesn't mount, and `fdisk` doesn't recognize it. However `lsusb` recognizes it. Output of `fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00013ee7

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   902584319   451291136   83  Linux
/dev/sda2      1936875518  1953523711     8324097    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda3       902584320  1936873471   517144576   83  Linux
/dev/sda5      1936875520  1953523711     8324096   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 04b4:0033 Cypress Semiconductor Corp. Mouse
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04d9:1702 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 13fe:3e00 Kingston Technology Company Inc. Flash Drive
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 147e:1001 Upek TCS5B Fingerprint sensor
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 041e:3f0e Creative Technology, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

It may be important to note that I know that the usb port works, and that the same problem occurs on other computers and other operating systems.

`dmesg` output:

```
[    0.546360] pcieport 0000:00:01.0: irq 40 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.546468] pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
[    0.546475] pciehp: PCI Express Hot Plug Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    0.546501] intel_idle: MWAIT substates: 0x42120
[    0.546502] intel_idle: v0.4 model 0x3C
[    0.546503] intel_idle: lapic_timer_reliable_states 0xffffffff
[    0.546567] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0
[    0.546569] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
[    0.546587] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1
[    0.546588] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
...
[    0.546702] ACPI: Requesting acpi_cpufreq
[    0.547073] thermal LNXTHERM:00: registered as thermal_zone0
[    0.547075] ACPI: Thermal Zone [TZ00] (28 C)
[    0.547199] thermal LNXTHERM:01: registered as thermal_zone1
[    0.547200] ACPI: Thermal Zone [TZ01] (30 C)
[    0.547212] GHES: HEST is not enabled!
[    0.547251] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 32 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    0.567645] 00:0a: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[    0.568407] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
[    0.569075] brd: module loaded
[    0.569408] loop: module loaded
[    0.569577] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    0.569616] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[    0.569617] tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
[    0.569638] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[    0.569659] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.569660] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    0.569717] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.569722] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: EHCI Host Controller
[    0.569726] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.569735] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: debug port 2
[    0.573619] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    0.573631] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: irq 20, io mem 0xf7318000
[    0.583807] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    0.583817] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    0.583818] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.583819] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    0.583820] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.11.0-14-generic ehci_hcd
[    0.583820] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.0
[    0.583870] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.583874] hub 1-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    0.583972] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.583976] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: EHCI Host Controller
[    0.583980] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    0.583988] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: debug port 2
[    0.587891] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    0.587900] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: irq 23, io mem 0xf7317000
[    0.599832] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    0.599838] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    0.599839] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.599839] usb usb2: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    0.599840] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.11.0-14-generic ehci_hcd
[    0.599841] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    0.599886] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.599888] hub 2-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    0.599937] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    0.599941] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    0.599942] ohci-platform: OHCI generic platform driver
[    0.599944] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.599999] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.600001] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.600005] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    0.600071] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    0.600085] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: irq 41 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.600114] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    0.600115] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.600116] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.600117] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.11.0-14-generic xhci_hcd
[    0.600118] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    0.600151] xHCI xhci_add_endpoint called for root hub
[    0.600152] xHCI xhci_check_bandwidth called for root hub
[    0.600164] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.600173] hub 3-0:1.0: 14 ports detected
[    0.601512] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.601516] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[    0.601526] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    0.601527] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.601528] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.601529] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 3.11.0-14-generic xhci_hcd
[    0.601530] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    0.601565] xHCI xhci_add_endpoint called for root hub
[    0.601565] xHCI xhci_check_bandwidth called for root hub
[    0.601576] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.601581] hub 4-0:1.0: 6 ports detected
[    0.607869] i8042: PNP: No PS/2 controller found. Probing ports directly.
[    0.610231] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    0.610234] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[    0.610287] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
...
[    0.610511] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    0.610543] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.25.0-ioctl (2013-06-26) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    0.610633] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    0.610753] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.610758] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    0.610814] TCP: cubic registered
[    0.610860] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    0.610958] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    0.610965] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    0.611117] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
[    0.611119] Loading module verification certificates
[    0.611615] MODSIGN: Loaded cert 'Magrathea: Glacier signing key: 4f57df1a3429640d83ffde722907e1377213486f'
[    0.611620] registered taskstats version 1
[    0.612807] Key type trusted registered
[    0.613777] Key type encrypted registered
[    0.614779] AppArmor: AppArmor sha1 policy hashing enabled
[    0.615110]   Magic number: 14:18:6
[    0.615145] memory memory50: hash matches
[    0.615192] rtc_cmos 00:06: setting system clock to 2014-01-25 02:02:05 UTC (1390615325)
[    0.616075] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
[    0.616076] EDD information not available.
[    0.616673] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1364K (ffffffff81d10000 - ffffffff81e65000)
[    0.616674] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 12288k
[    0.618093] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1036K (ffff8800016fd000 - ffff880001800000)
[    0.619120] Freeing unused kernel memory: 836K (ffff880001b2f000 - ffff880001c00000)
[    0.626651] systemd-udevd[145]: starting version 204
[    0.633032] video: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    0.637120] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: version 3.0
[    0.637221] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: irq 42 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.637257] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 6 ports 6 Gbps 0x3 impl SATA mode
[    0.637259] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: flags: 64bit ncq led clo pio slum part ems apst 
[    0.637261] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.641442] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[    0.641451] r8169 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    0.644381] scsi0 : ahci
[    0.644447] scsi1 : ahci
[    0.644500] scsi2 : ahci
[    0.644551] scsi3 : ahci
[    0.644596] scsi4 : ahci
[    0.644641] scsi5 : ahci
[    0.644725] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf7316000 port 0xf7316100 irq 42
[    0.644727] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf7316000 port 0xf7316180 irq 42
[    0.644729] ata3: DUMMY
[    0.644729] ata4: DUMMY
[    0.644730] ata5: DUMMY
[    0.644731] ata6: DUMMY
[    0.648276] r8169 0000:03:00.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.648386] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: RTL8168g/8111g at 0xffffc90000c38000, ac:22:0b:79:d9:19, XID 0c000800 IRQ 43
[    0.648387] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[    0.896284] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    0.964389] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    0.964403] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[    0.965516] ata1.00: ATA-9: ST1000DM003-1CH162, CC47, max UDMA/133
[    0.965518] ata1.00: 1953525168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    0.966108] ata2.00: ATAPI: ASUS     DRW-24F1ST   a, 1.00, max UDMA/100
[    0.966378] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    0.966494] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST1000DM003-1CH1 CC47 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    0.966580] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
[    0.966582] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    0.966595] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    0.966596] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    0.966602] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    0.966603] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    0.967087] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
[    0.968331] scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM            ASUS     DRW-24F1ST   a   1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    0.972004] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 40x/40x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    0.972006] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    0.972091] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[    0.972129] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[    1.015236]  sda: sda1 sda2 < sda5 > sda3
[    1.015464] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.032855] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8008
[    1.032857] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.032989] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.033095] hub 1-1:1.0: 6 ports detected
[    1.144640] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.277208] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8000
[    1.277210] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.277349] hub 2-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.277450] hub 2-1:1.0: 8 ports detected
[    1.445069] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.462463] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=041e, idProduct=3f0e
[    1.462465] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.462466] usb 3-1: Product: E-MU XMidi1X1 Tab
[    1.462467] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: E-MU Systems,Inc.
[    1.462468] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: E-MU-E6-3F0E-07D90A1E-1014A-TAB
[    1.529207] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 3499.997 MHz
[    1.629355] usb 3-10: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    1.646037] usb 3-10: New USB device found, idVendor=147e, idProduct=1001
[    1.646038] usb 3-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.646040] usb 3-10: Product: Fingerprint Sensor   
[    1.646041] usb 3-10: Manufacturer: TouchStrip        
[    1.646090] usb 3-10: ep 0x83 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[    1.813622] usb 3-13: new low-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    1.849713] usb 3-13: New USB device found, idVendor=04d9, idProduct=1702
[    1.849715] usb 3-13: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.849716] usb 3-13: Product: USB Keyboard
[    1.849717] usb 3-13: Manufacturer:  
[    1.849779] usb 3-13: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[    1.849781] usb 3-13: ep 0x82 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[    1.852444] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    1.876577] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.876578] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.877465] input:   USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-13/3-13:1.0/input/input2
[    1.877509] hid-generic 0003:04D9:1702.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [  USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-13/input0
[    1.880767] input:   USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-13/3-13:1.1/input/input3
[    1.880805] hid-generic 0003:04D9:1702.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [  USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-13/input1
[    2.017935] usb 3-14: new low-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    2.038985] usb 3-14: New USB device found, idVendor=04b4, idProduct=0033
[    2.038987] usb 3-14: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.039050] usb 3-14: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[    2.043137] input: HID 04b4:0033 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-14/3-14:1.0/input/input4
[    2.043274] hid-generic 0003:04B4:0033.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.00 Mouse [HID 04b4:0033] on usb-0000:00:14.0-14/input0
[    2.530776] Switched to clocksource tsc
[    3.165517] xor: automatically using best checksumming function:
[    3.203631]    avx       : 37158.000 MB/sec
[    3.204642] device-mapper: dm-raid45: initialized v0.2594b
[    3.363865] raid6: sse2x1   11976 MB/s
[    3.431967] raid6: sse2x2   15095 MB/s
[    3.500066] raid6: sse2x4   17415 MB/s
[    3.568163] raid6: avx2x1   23122 MB/s
[    3.636263] raid6: avx2x2   26820 MB/s
[    3.704362] raid6: avx2x4   31307 MB/s
[    3.704363] raid6: using algorithm avx2x4 (31307 MB/s)
[    3.704364] raid6: using avx2x2 recovery algorithm
[    3.706059] bio: create slab <bio-1> at 1
[    3.706158] Btrfs loaded
[    3.842959] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[    3.842961] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[    3.842962] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[    3.842963] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[    3.842964] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[    3.842966] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[    3.842967] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[    3.842968] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 02 00
[    3.842972] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 128
[    3.842973] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 16
[    3.843741] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[    3.843743] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[    3.843744] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[    3.843745] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[    3.843746] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[    3.843747] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[    3.843748] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[    3.843749] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 02 00
[    3.843752] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 128
[    3.843753] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 16
[    3.844525] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[    3.844526] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[    3.844527] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[    3.844528] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[    3.844529] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[    3.844531] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[    3.844531] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[    3.844532] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 02 00
[    3.844535] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 131072
[    3.844537] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 16384
[    3.845308] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[    3.845309] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[    3.845310] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[    3.845311] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[    3.845312] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[    3.845314] Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
[    3.845315] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[    3.845315] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 02 00
[    3.845319] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 131072
[    3.845320] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 16384
[    3.904478] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   13.680881] Adding 8324092k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:8324092k FS
[   13.754619] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   13.789615] systemd-udevd[448]: starting version 204
[   13.863561] wmi: Mapper loaded
[   13.863843] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   13.876759] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   13.876782] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[   13.879090] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[   13.883381] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[   13.883384] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   13.887275] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[   13.888412] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[   13.888476] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:01:00.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[   13.888610] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20130102 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
[   13.888615] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  319.32  Wed Jun 19 15:51:20 PDT 2013
[   13.896796] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[   13.899239] microcode: CPU0 sig=0x306c3, pf=0x2, revision=0x9
[   13.903847] SKU: Nid=0x1d sku_cfg=0x4047e629
[   13.903849] SKU: port_connectivity=0x1
[   13.903850] SKU: enable_pcbeep=0x0
[   13.903851] SKU: check_sum=0x00000007
[   13.903852] SKU: customization=0x000000e6
[   13.903853] SKU: external_amp=0x5
[   13.903854] SKU: platform_type=0x0
[   13.903855] SKU: swap=0x0
[   13.903855] SKU: override=0x1
[   13.904301] autoconfig: line_outs=4 (0x14/0x15/0x16/0x17/0x0) type:line
[   13.904302]    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   13.904304]    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   13.904305]    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   13.904306]    dig-out=0x11/0x1e
[   13.904306]    inputs:
[   13.904308]      Front Mic=0x19
[   13.904309]      Rear Mic=0x18
[   13.904310]      Line=0x1a
[   13.904311] realtek: No valid SSID, checking pincfg 0x4047e629 for NID 0x1d
[   13.904313] realtek: Enabling init ASM_ID=0xe629 CODEC_ID=10ec0892
[   13.910089] device-mapper: multipath: version 1.5.1 loaded
[   13.916034] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input5
[   13.916092] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Side as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input6
[   13.916136] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out CLFE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input7
[   13.916177] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Surround as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input8
[   13.916217] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Front as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input9
[   13.916258] input: HDA Intel PCH Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input10
[   13.916300] input: HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input11
[   13.916339] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input12
[   13.916534] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000001828-0x000000000000182f SystemIO conflicts with Region \PMIO 1 (20130517/utaddress-251)
[   13.916541] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   13.916543] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000001c30-0x0000000000001c3f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPRL 1 (20130517/utaddress-251)
[   13.916545] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000001c30-0x0000000000001c3f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPR_ 2 (20130517/utaddress-251)
[   13.916547] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   13.916553] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000001c00-0x0000000000001c2f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPRL 1 (20130517/utaddress-251)
[   13.916556] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000001c00-0x0000000000001c2f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPR_ 2 (20130517/utaddress-251)
[   13.916559] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   13.916560] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[   13.916571] hda_intel: Disabling MSI
[   13.916577] hda-intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle VGA-switcheroo audio client
[   13.916606] hda-intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling 64bit DMA
[   13.918898] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x21
[   13.918900] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   13.918901] ath: Country alpha2 being used: AU
[   13.918901] ath: Regpair used: 0x21
[   13.919872] hda-intel 0000:01:00.1: Enable delay in RIRB handling
[   13.920705] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[   13.920878] ieee80211 phy0: Atheros AR9485 Rev:1 mem=0xffffc90005300000, irq=19
[   13.982288] asus_wmi: ASUS WMI generic driver loaded
[   13.983091] asus_wmi: Initialization: 0x0
[   13.983103] asus_wmi: BIOS WMI version: 0.9
[   13.983123] asus_wmi: SFUN value: 0x0
[   13.983288] input: Eee PC WMI hotkeys as /devices/platform/eeepc-wmi/input/input13
[   13.983711] asus_wmi: Disabling ACPI video driver
[   13.988774] microcode: CPU1 sig=0x306c3, pf=0x2, revision=0x9
[   13.989081] microcode: CPU2 sig=0x306c3, pf=0x2, revision=0x9
[   13.989386] microcode: CPU3 sig=0x306c3, pf=0x2, revision=0x9
[   13.989683] microcode: CPU4 sig=0x306c3, pf=0x2, revision=0x9
[   13.989955] microcode: CPU5 sig=0x306c3, pf=0x2, revision=0x9
[   13.990228] microcode: CPU6 sig=0x306c3, pf=0x2, revision=0x9
[   13.990506] microcode: CPU7 sig=0x306c3, pf=0x2, revision=0x9
[   13.990795] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
[   13.994891] kvm: disabled by bios
[   14.011907] kvm: disabled by bios
[   14.036106] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   14.036108] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[   14.036109] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   14.036110] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   14.036111] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   14.036111] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   14.036112] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   14.036117] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: AU
[   14.037374] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: AU
[   14.037376] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[   14.037377] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[   14.037378] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2300 mBm)
[   14.037378] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2300 mBm)
[   14.037379] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
[   14.356003] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2/input14
[   14.356068] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2/input15
[   14.356127] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2/input16
[   14.850254] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   15.247898] init: failsafe main process (773) killed by TERM signal
[   15.362106] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[   15.362117] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   15.362118] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   15.362124] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   15.362125] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   15.362130] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   15.363584] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   15.363586] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   15.363589] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   15.363979] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   15.363983] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   15.363984] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   15.549198] init: avahi-cups-reload main process (898) terminated with status 1
[   15.577247] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   15.772071] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link down
[   15.938641] init: udev-fallback-graphics main process (935) terminated with status 1
[   16.860093] init: plymouth-stop pre-start process (1372) terminated with status 1
[   17.448891] wlan0: authenticate with bc:14:01:2a:96:e8
[   17.470086] wlan0: send auth to bc:14:01:2a:96:e8 (try 1/3)
[   17.474272] wlan0: authenticated
[   17.476516] wlan0: associate with bc:14:01:2a:96:e8 (try 1/3)
[   17.485683] wlan0: RX AssocResp from bc:14:01:2a:96:e8 (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=2)
[   17.485710] wlan0: associated
[   17.485714] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   17.485749] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[   17.487071] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[   17.487073] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
...
[   72.172480] usb 3-12: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[   72.189168] usb 3-12: New USB device found, idVendor=13fe, idProduct=3e00
[   72.189170] usb 3-12: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   72.189171] usb 3-12: Product: 2267 PRAM               
[   72.189171] usb 3-12: Manufacturer:                         
[   72.209613] usb-storage 3-12:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   72.209723] scsi6 : usb-storage 3-12:1.0
[   72.209783] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[   73.210329] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access              2267 PRAM        1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[   73.210496] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[   73.210974] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[   96.456242] hda-intel: IRQ timing workaround is activated for card #0. Suggest a bigger bdl_pos_adj.
```

Comment: I would have a look in the dmesg output to see what the kernel says when you plug the drive in .. that might yield a few more clues.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes writing ISO files junks my usbs. It seems to happen most when I try to partition space for persistent storage. What i normally do is power cycle then open gparted and format the usb.

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

then

```
sudo gparted
```

Comment: This is the first thing I'd try.

Comment: Tried that, didn't show up as a drive

Comment: Did you do
    sudo mount -a
That will mount everything that the kernal can mount.

Comment: Yes, and it didn't work.

Comment: can you give us the dmesg output that Steve asked for?

Comment: I edited my question to add the dmesg output.