# ExFAT USB drive not listed in /dev/sd

Tags: usb, mount

I've got an ExFAT USB3 drive that my Ubuntu laptop seemed to recognise, but no longer does.  I've read a few posts to try getting relevant/diagnostic information, but to no avail.  Any further advice gratefully received.

Timeline (numbers may help reference)

1. Drive inserted, some error message about exfat not being a known file system.  Read [HowToGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/235655/how-to-mount-and-use-an-exfat-drive-on-linux/) artitcle, installed suggested utilities
2. Drive inserted, no error message, but not automounted
3. Read suggestions for lsusb, fdisk, *disks* application.  None seem to list drive
4. Read [suggestion that gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409872/usb-memory-stick-wont-be-recognized-as-a-drive) may help: I don't see it as a device there
5. Read suggestion for dmesg -c output (below block).  It seems to suggest the device can be read to some extent, so maybe it just needs formatting?  I'm happy to take that approach: can't access the current data anyway!

> [ 3890.131506] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
>
> [ 3890.243557] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
>
> [ 3890.459553] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
>
> [ 3890.675510] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
>
> [ 3890.787600] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
>
> [ 3891.003582] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
>
> [ 3891.219558] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
>
> [ 3891.219752] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
>
> [ 3891.423643] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
>
> [ 3891.627575] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 8, error -71
>
> [ 3891.739566] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
>
> [ 3891.739738] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
>
> [ 3891.943759] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
>
> [ 3892.147574] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 9, error -71
>
> [ 3892.147625] usb usb3-port1: unable to enumerate USB device

Drive is a Corsair, but not a padlock, so don't *think* [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597622/corsair-padlock-usb-does-not-list-under-dev-sd) is relevant.
The gparted absence made me wonder whether the USB itself is knackered, but the error message at (1) and the dmesg output at (5) give me some hope.

Comment: Those messages show the USB itself is knackered.